# IDataReader from Oracle Overflows when returning decimal values

Tags: oracle, overflow, odp.net, idatareader

I have some code that is responsible for converting data from an `IDataReader` into an `IronPython.Runtime.List` of `PythonTuples`.  This same code is employed for several different kinds of database connections (including Access, Oracle and MySql).

Oracle's `OracleDecimal` datatype causes an overflow when calling `dataReader.GetValues()` when the cursor contains a value with a large precision.  This issue has been well documented, and the solutions always involve using specific methods on the `OracleDataAdapter`.  I only have an `IDataReader` interface.

Is there any way around this issue without binding my code specifically to ODP.NET?  Surely there must be some way to get at this data in a provider-agnostic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only provider agnostic method that I am aware of is to round the values in your select statement.  I've found that rounding to 15 decimal places usually does the trick.

Comment: I had to go back to the guy who wrote the script and get him to specifically change the SQL he's using.  Sad, but I was left with no choice.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be exactly what you're looking for, but the `System.Data.Common.DbDataReader` class has a `GetProviderSpecificValues` function that may do what you want

Comment: There are two problems with this approach: (1) I only have a reference to an interface, and (2) once I get an OracleDecimal back, the only handle I'd have to it would be as an `object`.